# How to compile ML model for AWS Inferentia with flexible input size?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I have an ML model from Huggingface, which essentially looks as follows:

```
import torch
from transformers import BloomTokenizerFast, BloomForCausalLM

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
device

tokenizer = BloomTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("bigscience/bloom-560m")
model = BloomForCausalLM.from_pretrained("bigscience/bloom-560m").to(device)

text = tokenizer.encode(seed)
inputs, past_key_values = torch.tensor([text[0]]), None

with torch.no_grad():
    while #condition met:
        model_out = model(input_ids=inputs.to(device), past_key_values=past_key_values)
        ...
        # Generate new inputs and go back to the start
```

Now I would like to deploy this model to Inf1 on AWS Sagemaker see [here](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sagemaker_neo_compilation_jobs/deploy_pytorch_model_on_Inf1_instance/pytorch_torchvision_neo_on_Inf1.html#Deploying-pre-trained-PyTorch-vision-models-with-Amazon-SageMaker-Neo-On-Inf1-Instance):

```
from sagemaker.pytorch.model import PyTorchModel

pytorch_model = PyTorchModel(
    model_data=model_path,
    role=role,
    entry_point="my_entry_point_file.py",
    framework_version="1.5.1",
    py_version="py3",
)

neo_model = pytorch_model.compile(
    target_instance_family="ml_inf1",
    input_shape={"input0": [1, 3, 224, 224]},
    output_path=compiled_model_path,
    framework="pytorch",
    framework_version="1.5.1",
    role=role,
    job_name=compilation_job_name,
)
```

However, in my case I get

```
UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Compilation job bloom-compiled-inf-inf1-202304-1921-4203: Failed. Reason: ClientError: CompilationError: Unable to compile model for ml_inf1:', 'No operations were successfully partitioned and compiled to neuron for this model - aborting trace!')  For further troubleshooting common failures please visit: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/neo-troubleshooting-compilation.html
```

I believe the main problem is the following: Whereas `inputs` can be considered of length `[1,1]`, the variable `past_key_values` is much more complex. In this case, it is

- a tuple of length 24
- each entry is a tuple itself of length 2
- the two entries are torch tensors of size `[16, 64, 6]` and `[16, 6, 64]`

My question is now, what can I do such that it works on Inf1?

I could imagine that either

- there is a way to enter the right `input_shape`, which can be something like `{‘var1’: [1,1,28,28], ‘var2’:[1,1,28,28]}` (I do not know how to display the more complex tuple-tensor structure as outlined above)
- or can we split `past_key_values` such that we can build `input_shape` easily?

Any suggestions to solving that problem would be very appreciated.